# Hashability of Abstract Classes

Tags: python, oop, hash

I am taking an introductory college course on Python and we just began discussing OOP. At the same time, we are discussing hashability. By definition, an object is hashable if it has a defined `__hash__` method and a defined `__eq__` such that any two equal objects must have the same hash value. Given these simple conditions, suppose we had the `Toy` class defined below:

```
Class Toy:
    def __init__(self, values):
       self._elems = []

    def increase(self, value):
       self._elems.append(value)
    
    def __eq__(self, other):
       return self._elems == other._elems

    def __hash__(self):
       return id(self)
```

While my textbook asserts that this class is hashable, I do not understand how that is possible. For instance, I could hypothetically modify two pre-existing `Toy` objects such that their `_elems` attributes were identical. Therefore, when compared for equality, these two objects would be considered equal. However, the two objects will necessarily have different `id` values; so, how could they possibly return the same hash value?

Comment: Yeah, that class is just broken.

Comment: I don't think the textbook's example makes sense. This class would not work in a reasonable way as the key in a dictionary, for example.

Comment: By the definition you gave us, that class is not hashable.  Two Toys that are == to each other are not guaranteed to have the same hash value.  (And why does your `__init__` method take a `values` argument and then ignore it.?